# How to deal with this conflicting type error

Tags: c

[The error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ji350.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int atoi(char s[]){
    int i, n;
    
    n = 0;
    
    for (i=0; s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9'; i++) {
        n=10*n +(s[i] - '0');
    }
    
    return n;
}

int main()
{
    char s[] ={'1','2','0','\0'};
    printf("%d\n", atoi(s));
    return 0;
}
```

This is a character convert algorithm. But I cannot compile it correctly.

I figured it out. It seems that I need to rename my atoi function. Once I changed that part. The conflicting type error disappeared.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Would you mind editing your post and adding some more detail?  Specifically, what do you mean that you can't compile it correctly?

Comment: Compiles fine - https://onlinegdb.com/UrE6tCMS4.

Comment: What compiler are you using? (there is an `atoi()` function already in `stdlib.h` It should not prevent the compile, but may wand based on the compiler you are using.

Comment: I am using Xcode

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The definition is incompatible with the `stlib.h` version, which declares its argument as `const char *`.

Comment: Ah, good catch @TomKarzes. I don't know how xcode handles weak declarations, but the lack of the `const` qualifier does add another hurdle.